# IntelliJ IDEA Is Not Detecting Vuetify Components In Nuxt.js Project

Tags: intellij-idea, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with IntelliJ IDEA. 
yesterday I started a Nuxt.js Project With Vuetify as UI framework.
But IntelliJ IDEA It not detecting Vuetify Components. it Showing them as an Unknown HTML tag. And When I use the idea's Autocomplete It Importing That Component, although Vuetify Is Already Registered As Global COmponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bug in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to vote or comment here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32886

Comment: Thank You! I Got A Temporary Fix From The Post.

Answer (score 2):

**It is a bug in IntelliJ Idea**

For a temporary workaround, download The js file and paste it in your Vuetify project dir. [Note: No Need To Reference The js File.]

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vuetifyjs/api-generator/master/dist/fakeComponents.js

Ref:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32886
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4590#issuecomment-414300395

EDIT: THE Problem is fixed. just upgrade the ide